# Cache objects as Immutable classes

Tags: java, performance, caching, immutability

I am asking very generic question and the answer can vary from requirement to requirement, but for "general" or "rule of thumb", can we say the following is a good design rule:

> The classes to be cached (static/reference data) should be designed as
>   immutable, with exceptions reasoned.

What could be design/performance issues with the above statement, if this is not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JohnB has a good answer about the underlying data.

If, however, the question is referring to the immutability of the cached classes themselves (which are holding the data in the cache), then the answer is that mutable classes can cause thread-safety issues if the instances of the classes are referenced by multiple threads (as can often happen with data shared via a cache).  Additionally, "accidental" modification of the data may occur, where a shared instance is unintentionally modified (because the modifying code did not know that the data was shared).

Answer (score 2):

This is because of what a cache does, which is hold data rather than retrieving it from the data source again. For example, you query the database for a value then put it in a memory-based cache so you don't have to query the DB again. However, if the value in the DB can change then the value in the cache will be out of date and your application will be using the wrong data.

Therefore, caching is best if the data cannot change during the live of the application. If the data can change, then a strategy must be developed to regularly check to see if the data has changed.

Comment: +1 for being so simple. This should have been marked as the correct answer. Your answer scores +2 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

What jtahlborn is explaining in other words : an immutable class will provide methods to obtain "static" data.

If your class is immutable, you will NOT have setters except the parameters in the constructor.

Take care making this : immutable classes are **not** made to be used only once, it would result in a performance loss, since copies of inner attributes have to be done each time you access the get... methods.

Example :

```
class MyImmutableThing {

  private final String myProperty;

  MyImmutableThing(String myProperty) {
    this.myProperty = myProperty;
  }

  String obtainMyProperty() {
    return myProperty;
  }

    // note there is no mean to modify the myProperty value : the original value remains ;)
    // That's it !
}
```

Comment: Take care of this kind of situation : here the constructor will make a first copy of its parameter to put into the property. If you do this with custom/large immutable objects, these copies can bring some performance issues to you...

Comment: `_myProperty` is not a copy of the `String` passed in to the constructor. Object size is irrelevant since only an *oop* (reference) is copied. That being said, `_myProperty` should be a field.

Comment: Strings are by definition immutable, then each affectation makes a copy.Try this :
 String a = "toto";
 String b = a;
 a = "titi";
 System.out.println(b);

Comment: that's replacing the reference, yes. Try `String a = "toto"; String b = a; assert System.identityHashCode(a) == System.identityHashCode(b);`

Comment: Okay, but let's look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html , the identityHashCode and hashCode methods from System return a calculated value based on the contents, not on the memory address/reference. Thus, the assert will be true because there are no change in both values, whose are "hash-equal".

Comment: I think you had some total failure comprehending the specification for `identityHashCode`. Try `assert System.identityHashCode("toto") == System.identityHashCode(new String(new char[] { 't', 'o', 't', 'o' }));`

Comment: [`System.identityHashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)) is declared so that it __returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned by the default method hashCode(), whether or not the given object's class overrides hashCode().__ i.e. it's based on object *identity*, not semantic equality (which is what `String.hashCode` gives)

Comment: System.out.println(System.identityHashCode("toto"));
 System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(new String(new char[] { 't', 'o', 't', 'o' }))); returns me 1196085910 and
21469803... don't sure I understand what you are telling to me.

Comment: I learned something I misunderstood for years (not yet fluent english ;) ). Many thanks !

Comment: No problem, just glad you figured it out :-p